# Can't reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

I installed the Visual Studio 2010 SDK on my development machine and a tutorial I am following asks me to reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.  It is supposed to be under the .NET tab according to the book.  I can only see Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Commands.  I have installed and uninstalled and reinstalled, rebooted etc.

Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using .NET 3.5.  Updated it to .NET 4.0 and the assemblies were available.